# C++ method that returns a type instead of an object

Tags: c++, generics

Having the following case

```
template <typename A, typename B>
void f(A a, std::function<void(B)> f2)
{
  B b = f1(a);

  f2(b);
}
```

A, B are structures, the association between A and B is 1 to 1 in my logic.

How can I create a function that receives type A as input, and results in type B as output so I can write instead:

```
template <typename A>
void f(A a, std::function<void(TypeFunction(A))> f2)
{
  auto b = f1(a);

  f2(b);
}
```

Comment: Where does `f1` come from in this code? And how exactly is this "association" defined?

Comment: it is unclear where in the second snippet you want to "return a type". Do you want to declare `b` to be of the same type as the return type of f1 ? It is already.  What is f1 ?

Comment: it seems like you want to allow the user to call the functions as `f(a,fun)` without needing to specify `B`. However, if `f1` does return `B` then there is no need to use `B` as template argument in the first place. What is `f1` ?

Comment: maybe the issues is caued by using `std::function` when there is no need to use it. `f` can and perhaps should be `template <typename A, typename F> void f(A a, F f2)`

Comment: `decltype` is probably what you need to use.

Comment: @UnholySheep f1 is a random function that, let's say is defined above.

Comment: @Eljay How can I use decltype in the header of the function?

Answer (score 2):

If there are no other overloads of `f`, then you don't need to specify `B` at all.

```
template<typename A, typename FB>
void f(A a, FB f2) {
    auto b = f1(a);
    f2(b);
}
```

If there are other overloads, such that you *require* a `std::function` argument, then you can use `decltype`

```
template<typename A>
void f(A a, std::function<void(decltype(f1(a)))> f2) {
    auto b = f1(a);
    f2(b);
}
```